# how to join many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my database:

[image]
`contact_photo` and `contact_video` are 2 "**join**" tables. They have a **foreign key** to `my_contact` table and a **foreign key** to `photo/video` tables.

Is there a way, with one query, to retrieve all the records in those 5 tables, starting from the value of `my_contact.id`?

I know how to join, for example, `my_contact`, `contact_photo`, and `photo`,
 but I have no idea how to join those 5 tables together.

I tried:

```
 query = "SELECT * " +
           "FROM my_contact m " +
           "INNER JOIN contact_photo cp ON ( m._id = cp.id_contact ) " +
           "INNER JOIN photo p ON ( cp.id_photo = p._id) " +
           "INNER JOIN contact_video cv ON ( m._id = cv.id_contact ) " +
           "INNER JOIN video v ON ( cv.id_video = v._id) ";
```

But I get no record, even if `my_contact`, `contact_photo` and `photo` have records (`contact_video` and `video` are empty tables). Is there something wrong in my logic?

The result I'd like to get are records like these:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| my_contact._id | photo.id_photo_on_device | photo.uri                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1        |            23            | C:\PROGRAM|....            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| my_contact._id | video.id_video_on_device | video.uri                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1        |            36            | C:\PROGRAM|....            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actually, looking at the records I'd like to get it seems there's something wrong in my logic.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Think about how your result set shall look like. Of course you can just join, but then you would get records for all combinations of photos and videos (i.e. for a contact with photo1 and photo2 and video1 and video2, you'd get a row for photo1, video1, one for photo1, video2, one for photo2, video1, and one for photo2, video2). Is this what you want? Show us how you want the result to look like in your request.

Comment: I edited my post,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a `union all` query.  The structure will resemble this:

```
select c.uri
, c.i_contact_on_device
, other useful fields
from my_contact c join contact_photo cp on c._id = cp.id_contact
join photo p on p._id = cp.id_photo
union all
same general idea, but for videos
```

Note that not all fields will be useful.  For example, even if you wanted the the _id field from my_contact, you probably only need it once.  That's why selecting fields from the junction tables is probably unnecessary.